# Java ArrayList clone improved run-time

Tags: java, list, arraylist, clone

This is the question:https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations/

This is my solution 1:

```
   public class Solution {

    public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k){
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        combine(n, k, 1, result, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return result;
    }

    public void combine(int n, int k , int start, List<List<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> l){
        if(k == 0){
            result.add(l);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = start; i <= n; ++i){

            l.add(i);
            combine(n, k - 1, i + 1, result, l);
        }
    }


    }
```

Result: small test cases passed. But big test cases time exceed.

Submission Result: Time Limit Exceeded
Last executed input:    10, 5

Solution 2:

```
public class Solution {

public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k){
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    combine(n, k, 1, result, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    return result;
}

public void combine(int n, int k , int start, List<List<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> l){
    if(k == 0){
        result.add(l);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = start; i <= n; ++i){
        ArrayList<Integer> a = (ArrayList<Integer>) l.clone();
        a.add(i);
        combine(n, k - 1, i + 1, result, a);
    }
}


}
```

Passed all test cases.

the main difference is clone of the list.
But why?
is the solution A wrong or just slow?
Why using clone is faster here?
Really confused.

Comment: If you're not going to modify the solutions, you can do better with shared linked lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution is indeed incorrect. Try invoking `combine(5,3)`, and sending it to `System.out`, and you'll see the output for the first is:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5]]

You'll notice that it's the same list in each index position - you really do need to create a new array each time. For the second, correct solution, the output is:

> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

This means that the first solution is slower because you're adding numbers to a larger and larger list each time. For higher values of n and k, that list can be very large, and copying the backing array of `ArrayList` when it needs to expand becomes a very expensive operation - much more expensive than copying/creating a number of small lists.

Comment: How could he fix the first solution? What die he do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig The fix is to create a new array each time, which is what he does in the second solution.